# FFMPEG: cut, add watermark and merge

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 video files (input.mp4,leadout.mp4) and an image (watermark.png). I need to cut the first video to 54 seconds, add the watermark and then merge it with the second video.
I achieved this calling ffmpeg 3 times:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i input.mp4 -t 54 -c copy temp.mp4

ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -i watermark.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0" -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 temp2.mp4

ffmpeg -i temp2.mp4 -i leadout.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 output.mp4
```

This is very inefficient and time-consuming, as you can see. Is there any way to use filter_complex to do these 3 actions at once?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can combine all three commands into one:

```
ffmpeg -t 54 -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -i leadout.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay[v0];[v0][0:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 27 -preset ultrafast -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```